# Convertir comando MySQL Raw a LINQ C# Entity Framework Core 3.1

Tags: entity-framework-core, c#-8.0

Soy nuevo en .NET Core y quiero migrar la siguiente query que tenia en C# .NET Framework, para usarla en .NET Core 3.1. (He tratado, pero aun lo he logrado).

Lo que hace la consulta, es obtener el valor máximo de la columna 'valor' durante la ultima hora tomando como referencia la variable 'localtime'.

```
string localtime = "2020-06-21 04:00:00";
string nombreParam1 = "@coord1";
string nombreParam2 = "@coord2";
```

```
select max(valor) as resultado from table where datetime between DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB('" + localtime + "', interval 1 hour), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') and " +
"DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB('" + localtime + "', interval 1 hour), '%Y-%m-%d %H:59:59') and Coord1 = " + nombreParam1 + " and Coord2 = " + nombreParam2 + "";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución y la publico por si le sirve a alguien:

```
var tStamp = DateTime.Now;             
var startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(tStamp.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:00:00")).AddHours(-1); 
var endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(tStamp.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:59:59")).AddHours(-1);
```

---

```
using (var context = new dbContext())
{
    int? valor = context.table
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Where(x => x.datetime >= startDate && x.datetime <= endDate)                        
        .Where(x => x.coord1 == nombreParam1 && x.coord2 == nombreParam2)
        .Max(x => (int?)x.resultado); 
}
```